# Simple Regex for upper and lower case letters, numbers, and a few symbols

Tags: regex, preg-match

How can I create a Regular expression to match the following characters:

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 " -  ? . ', !
```

... as well as new lines and spaces

Comment: Is this literally what you want to match or is it any Capital A-Z letter, followed by a space, followed by a lowercase a-z.... or is this a set of conditions either OR. Could you be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will match any single one of those characters:

```
[A-Za-z0-9"?.',! \n\r-]
```

There's a good chance you want something like:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9"?.',! \n\r-]+$
```

Or possibly a bit simpler will meet your needs:

```
^[\w\s"?.',!-]+$
```

Remembering that if this is inside a string, you will need to escape either the `"` or `'` in that (either by doubling up, or by prefixing with a backslash).

Also note that the `-` is last so that it is not treated as a range inside the character class. (Can also be placed first, or prefixed with backslash to prevent that).

The `\w` will match a "word" character, which is almost always `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.
The `\s` will match a whitespace character, (i.e. space,tab,newline,carriage return).

But really **you need to give more context to what you're trying to do** so people can suggest more fitting solutions.